# How to access file using pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, nsurl

I have an mp3 file in my Supporting Files folder which I would like to play in my app on a loop. I am using the following code to attempt this:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smoothjazz" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Supporting Files"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite
[player play];
```

However, this returns an error saying:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

How can I access my file in supporting files, and play it as intended? All help appreciated.

EDIT: SOLVED! See my answer for how I did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Supporting Files` folder is the Supporting Files group you see in every Xcode project by default than the inFolder: argument is not needed as `Supporting Files` is a Xcode grouping and not a real folder. So you should do:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smoothjazz" 
                                                          ofType:@"mp3"];
```

This should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work :\ Could it be that the simulator's volume isn't on?

Comment: I solved it! The issue was that I declared the AVAudioPlayer in the viewDidLoad method; but you were right, I didn't need to use "inDirectory:" - Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

May be the path you getting through this will be nil,

`NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smoothjazz" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Supporting Files"];`.

Make sure you properly added the files to your bundle.
And add the proper checks before committing operations, its the best practice. Like follows, Hope this helps you..

```
// Define NSFileManager and add the proper checks for file existance like as follows.
NSFileManager *filemgr  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smoothjazz" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Supporting Files"];

if (filemgr fileExistsAtPath:imageURL.absoluteString])
{
// Your code to play the sound file
}
```

Comment: I just tried this (replacing the imageUrl with soundFilePath), and put an NSLog in the if statement - Apparently, the file does exist! However, the sound still does not play... Could it be the simulator's sound setting? I've used '[player setVolume:1.0];', but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Spag was right - I didn't need to use 'inDirectory:', as it was in the supporting files. But the main problem was that I declared the AVAudioPlayer in the viewDidLoad method, meaning that it's lifespan was only as long as the method (or something along those lines). So I declared the variable as a global variable, and the problem was solved! The music plays.